# How to run first batch file and go to second batch file without waiting for finishing first batch file

Tags: chef-infra

I want to run two different batch files in chef.
Problem is, after executing first batch file it is waiting to finish and then executing batchfile2. Without waiting for batchfile1 completion i want to execute batchfile2.

```
batch "run-script1" do
  code  "batchfile1"
  cwd "path"
  action :run
end
```

## waiting to complete batchfile1 execution and then executing batchfile2

```
batch "run-script2" do
  code  "batchfile2"
  cwd "path"
  action :run
end
```

Without waiting for batchfile1 completion i want to execute batchfile2

Answer (score 1):

if you have a file named `batchfile1` in `path` path location, and you expect it will be executed... then it won't happened since this is not how [`batch` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_batch.html) works.

i can assume that the first `batch` resource failed to execute, causing chef-client run to fail and thus the second `batch` resource is not executed.

> The batch resource creates and executes a temporary file (similar to how the script resource behaves), rather than running the command inline.
>   for instance:
>
> ```
> batch 'echo some env vars' do
>   code <<-EOH
>     echo %TEMP%
>     echo %SYSTEMDRIVE%
>     echo %PATH%
>     echo %WINDIR%
>     EOH
> end
> ```